# how play ogg/ape/wv/wma using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying decode ogg,ape,wma,wv file formats
I have posted the code below, but I'm having too much noise at the output

```
 av_init_packet(&packet);
        fmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

        if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, szfile, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            LOGE("Cannot open input file\n");
        }
        if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            LOGE("Cannot find stream information\n");
        }

        /* select the audio stream */
        ret = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            LOGE("Cannot find a audio stream in the input file\n");
        }

        audio_stream_index = ret;
        dec_ctx = fmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->codec;

        LOGE(" ogg code %d codec id%d\n",AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS,dec_ctx->codec_id);

        LOGE("avcodec_find_decoder\n");


        dec = avcodec_find_decoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
                        if (!dec) {

              __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "BroovPlayer", "avcodec_find_decoder failed %d Name:%s\n", dec_ctx->codec_id, dec_ctx->codec_name);


                        }


        if ((ret = avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            LOGE("Cannot open audio decoder\n");
        }




        //dec_ctx->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P;
        LOGS("Stage 5 sample fmt %d",dec_ctx->sample_fmt);
        LOGE("Stage 5");
        LOGD("........%d", packet.size);
        while (1)
        {

               if ((ret = av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
               {
                   //LOGE("Stage........... %d",ret);
                   break;
               }
               if (packet.stream_index == audio_stream_index)
               {
                       avcodec_get_frame_defaults(frame);
                       got_frame = 0;
                      // LOGE("file size=%d packet_index=%d",packet.size,packet.dts);


                       ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(dec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, &packet);
                     //  LOGE("len=%d",ret);
                       if (ret < 0)
                       {
                           LOGE("Error decoding audio\n");
                           continue;
                       }

                       if (!got_frame) {
                                    /* stop sending empty packets if the decoder is finished */
                                    if (!packet.data && dec->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_DELAY)
                                        //flush_complete = 1;
                                    continue;
                                }

                       if (got_frame)
                       {
                           // LOGE("begin frame decode\n");
                            int data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, dec_ctx->channels,frame->nb_samples,dec_ctx->sample_fmt, 1);
                           // LOGE("after frame decode\n");

                            jbyte *bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
                            memcpy(bytes, frame->data[0], data_size); //
                            (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bytes, 0);
                            (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj,play, array, data_size);

                       }
                       packet.size -= ret;
                       packet.data += ret;
                       packet.pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;


                 }
          }

               av_free_packet(&packet);



            when ,i am playing ogg/ape/wv audio file format .



          please help me to minimize the noise, as less as possible
```

or if any other approach is there to decode these file formats then please let me know

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure decoders for file formats. Read document how to configure it. Good samples where you can start: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/, https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg